# Write script in linux to display image on webpage

Tags: html, linux, bash, debian

So i'm trying to write a script to print out an image on a webpage. I was able to print out header tags like h1 but I could not get image tags to work. Assume my file structure is:

```
 usr
  - lib
    - cgi-bin
      - test.sh
      - images
       - a.jpg
       - b.jpg
```

I made a script file named test.sh and a folder of images named images and allowed them to be executable. Here is the file test.sh that has the code the I call from my browser by typing http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.sh in my browser

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo 
echo <h1>Test</h1>
echo <img src=images/a.jpg>
```

The web server i'm using is Apache2

Comment: highlight code block, hit `{}` button in editor, or ctrl-k, which indents the lines by 4 spaces, causing them to become code blocks...

Comment: `images/a.jpg` is going to be requested as `http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/images/a.jpg`, and since that's a CGI directory, the server is going to try and EXECUTE that file, which will undoubtedly fail: the file's probably not executable (`+x` perm) and wouldn't be actually executable even if the permissions were set.

Comment: What is serving the files, because often `cgi-bin` is treated specially?

Comment: With that html the browser will try to get `images/a.jpg` which the webserver will likely translate to `usr/lib/images/a.jpg` which will fail since it doesn't exist. Move the images to the webroot or fix the `src` attribute path.

Comment: I'm new to Debian so i'm not sure where the webroot folder but I did adjust the src folder. I moved the diceimages folder out of cgi-bin to /usr/lib and change the src attribute to "../diceimages/. I still dont see the images

Comment: that's unrelated to Debian but related to the webserver you are using (and which you haven't disclosed yet)

Comment: The web server i'm using is Apache2

Comment: I was able to get it working. I just moved the images out of cgi-bin folder and referenced the location of the images in the src attribute of the image tag. Thanks!